# PG could not connect to server when trying to install postgresql on Manjaro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pgadmin, pg, manjaro, dbconnection

I tried to install postgresql on Linux Manjaro and create db and user.

I have executed next commands:

```
$ sudo pacman -S postgresql postgis
$ sudo -u postgres -i
```

Than

```
$ initdb  -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'
```

returns 'access denied' error.

I was trying to create connection via pgAdmin4. 
Than I got next error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I found a lot of similar issues. So tried some solves like changing the path of db location or reinstall postgresql.

My aim is to run pg in Rails. But now I have

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

when I am trying to execute

```
$ rails db:create
```

Seems, I do not understand the whole way of pg configuring. Thank you!

UPDATED:
Next commands solved the problem:

```
sudo pacman -R postgresql
sudo pacman -S postgresql postgis
sudo su - postgres -c "initdb -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
systemctl start postgresql
systemctl status postgresql
sudo su - postgres
createuser user1
createdb -O user1 db1
psql db1 -U user1
```

Comment: You might want to consider deleting the question. Its some-what off topic and was resolved in a way that is unlikely to be particularly helpful to anybody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next commands solved the problem:

```
sudo pacman -R postgresql
sudo pacman -S postgresql postgis
sudo su - postgres -c "initdb -E UTF8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
systemctl start postgresql
systemctl status postgresql
sudo su - postgres
createuser user1
createdb -O user1 db1
psql db1 -U user1
```